# change the dataframe in python instead of column value as an own column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this: df

| Country | Year | Area | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albania | 2018 | T | 250 |
| Albania | 2018 | NT | 150 |
| Albania | 2019 | T | 260 |
| Albania | 2019 | NT | 180 |
| USA | 2018 | T | 200 |
| USA | 2018 | NT | 120 |
| USA | 2019 | T | 280 |
| USA | 2019 | NT | 180 |
| Oman | 2018 | T | 260 |
| Oman | 2018 | NT | 160 |
| Oman | 2019 | T | 220 |
| Oman | 2019 | NT | 120 |
| UK | 2018 | T | 290 |
| UK | 2018 | NT | 140 |
| UK | 2019 | T | 290 |
| UK | 2019 | NT | 130 |

But I want these ouput

| Country | Year | T | NT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albania | 2018 | 250 | 150 |
| Albania | 2019 | 260 | 180 |
| USA | 2018 | 200 | 120 |
| USA | 2019 | 280 | 180 |
| Oman | 2018 | 260 | 160 |
| Oman | 2019 | 220 | 120 |
| UK | 2018 | 290 | 140 |
| UK | 2019 | 290 | 130 |

Is there a way to put the column values into columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):**

```
dfx=pd.crosstab([df['Country'],df['Year']], df['Area'],values=df['count'],aggfunc='first').reset_index()
```

**Output**:

```
Area  Country  Year   NT    T
0     Albania  2018  150  250
1     Albania  2019  180  260
2        Oman  2018  160  260
3        Oman  2019  120  220
4          UK  2018  140  290
5          UK  2019  130  290
6         USA  2018  120  200
7         USA  2019  180  280
```

Comment: If you have nan values, the Created columns (NT and T) will have nan in rows equivalent to those nan values.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the [`pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) method. For example,

```py
df.pivot(index=['Country', 'Year'], columns='Area', values='count').reset_index(level=1)
```

**Output**

```py
Area     Year   NT    T
Country
Albania  2018  150  250
Albania  2019  180  260
Oman     2018  160  260
Oman     2019  120  220
UK       2018  140  290
UK       2019  130  290
USA      2018  120  200
USA      2019  180  280
```